# Very odd that my post correcting another poster was deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, not-an-answer, specific-answer

I'm unclear how my post correcting an incorrect "answer" was deleted as "off topic".

Per your faq "commentary on the question or other answers" is grounds for deletion.

What about when those "answers" aren't?

One would think that it is valuable to correct misinformation...oh well.

Comment: Link please? ...

Comment: Giving feedback on other's posts is perfectly acceptable. However, you need to do it through commenting, not adding another post. Unfortunately, you haven't earned the privilege to comment yet, thus making your post unacceptable.

Answer (score 15):

Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, it's not a traditional discussion forum. As such, the answers section is strictly reserved for answers that directly and preferably fully answer the question. Anything else does not belong in an answer.

That said, we have two ways of providing feedback on existing answers, [comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) and (up/down)votes. Both mechanisms are considered privileges and you'll gain access to them after you've spend some time on the site and earned a bit of [reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work). You will need 15 reputation points to upvote, 50 to comment everywhere, and 125 to downvote. However there's no reputation requirement to ask or answer questions, so if you feel a question hasn't been sufficiently answered, you should definitely go for it.

We have several other mechanisms that are tied to reputation. If you are interested in more details on what abilities you can gradually unlock on the site you should take a look at the comprehensive list on our [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges).

Comment: @lucifer "there's only 1 reputation requirement..." isn't correct syntactically. If you must change the sentence, then you could say something like "there's only 1 reputation point required...", but I don't see any reason to change it at all.

Comment: sorry its my misunderstanding.

Comment: @lucifer Don't worry about it, I've done quite a few bad edits myself... Heh, I remember completely screwing up the title on one of Jeff Atwood's questions once. Not only was my edit unnecessary, but I also introduced a spelling mistake, it happens. Keep on editing. ;)

Comment: Thanks all for clarifying. Post url is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389043/why-is-java-lang-thread-in-the-google-app-engine-whitelist/16073410#16073410